# How can I duplicate "Add Custom Field" with just JavaScript?

Tags: custom-field, javascript

I frequently need to add several Name-Value pairs to the Custom Fields of a post. At present I add these one by one, by entering the Name and Value and clicking Add Custom Field.

I'd like to speed this up by entering several pairs into a single box (textarea, prompt, whatever), and have some JavaScript parse them and add them as though I had entered them manually.

(Why JavaScript? Because I don't have access to edit any PHP or install any new plugins. I'm doing this browser-side, with Greasemonkey.)

As far as I'm aware, the Add Custom Field button submits the Name-Value pair with AJAX, but I'm not familiar enough with jQuery or WordPress to find the exact code that does this so that I can copy it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick search shows that related part of form is generated by [`meta_form()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L516) function. Start from there I guess.

Also note that you will need to retrieve from source and submit [nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) that protects that form. I am not sure if submitting single field invalidates the nonce there, but that also might be the case.